# JAXB IllegalAnnotationExceptions after JPA annotations were added

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-data-jpa, jaxb

I read a couple of threads here but still can't understand why am i getting this exception. Everything was fine and i was able to get a correct response from my SOAP web-service with Spring. But then i added Spring Data JPA and a couple of annotations to persist data in my DB and exception started to appear in response XML.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "number", propOrder = {
    "code",
    "fileNames",
    "error"
})
@Entity
public class Number {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private int number;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @Column(name = "code")
    protected String code;

    @Column(name = "filenames")
    @Convert(converter = ListConverter.class)
    //@Transient
    protected List<String> fileNames;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @Column(name = "error")
    private String error;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String value) {
        this.code = value;
    }

    public List<String> getFileNames() {
        if (fileNames == null) {
            fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.fileNames;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String value) {
        this.error = value;
    }

}
```

And here's what i get in response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en">2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: How does the version look like that worked?
You should see a full exception on the console. What does it say?

Comment: @JensSchauder i don't see any exceptions on the console, service is working fine after this response, i can send another request which will be processed. 
Version, that is working: no JPA annotations and no additional fields in Number class - id and number. 
When i removed number field, response was "1 count of IllegalAnnotationExceptions" , so i removed id right after and it's working.
Is there a way to keep them in class and make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added @XmlTransient annotation for "id" and "number" fields and everything is working now.